# Will tlp's CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC settings conflict with the Mate cpufreq widget?

Tags: power-management, cpu-frequency

I want to find a way to set the CPU governor to `powersave` on boot, and then manage it through the CPU frequency scaling monitor widget. However, the comments in the config file of tlp say "You *must* disable your distribution's governor settings or conflicts will occur". Does the widget count as such?